# Take affect the change in Html or in the code

Tags: javascript, html

**Info**
When i make some change in my code in `js` file in my editor some time is not take affect in the `chrome`, i need to open in the `view-source` find it in the url and refresh to make the change.?

**Question**
Why is this happen and how i can avoid it.?
I need to save all in the editor and take affect everywhere  .

Comment: Another easy option could be as follows: In Chrome, press F12 to bring up Developer Tools for your web page.  Then, make changes to your JavaScript file.  The right-click the refresh button (which is next to the home button) in the Chrome browser toolbar. Select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".  This will do as it says, empty/clear cached resources and perform a hard reload.  When you have Developer Tools open, you get this shortcut to empty cache and reload the page.  Otherwise, it's a few clicks away in Chrome settings.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC and loading scripts in bundles, you can look at the ResolveBundleUrl method, which creates a virtual path to the script...which I believe would cause the browser to reload the script file each time the page is loaded.  For example, @Scripts.Render(BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/mymainbundle", true))

Answer (score 0):

Disable caching. Open the developer window find "network" and check "disable cache".

In Chrome F12 -> network -> disable cache

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because your browser tries cache js script each tume )